# Remove .jsp extension in the url using UrlRewriteFilter framework

Tags: jsp, url, jetty

I have seen many posts on this issue, But none have worked for me.

For some reason I want to remove '.jsp' extension for all the webpages.

The application is running on Jetty server.

I am using UrlRewriteFilter for this.
 For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/location.jsp
```

Replaced with

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/location
```

urlrewrite.xml is the following:

```
<rule>
   <from>/myapp/location</from>
    <to type="forward">/location.jsp</to> </rule>
```

I am not successful with this rule. Suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: I would think the path should be the same on both from and to, so why did you drop myapp from the to?

Comment: @developerwjk 's suggestion would be the first to check

Comment: I did add the /myapp and tested. It did not change any thing

Comment: So you are typing http://localhost:8080/myapp/location in the address bar, right? And what is happening? You get a 404 error?